# Nothing happens when I close maximized MDI child form

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, mdichild, maximize-window

I have `Form1` with 2 radio buttons (`rb1` and `rb2`) and one ordinary button (`btn`). When I click on `btn` I should open `Form2`, as MDI child of `Form1` if `rb1` is checked, or as ordinary `Dialog` if `rb2` is checked. Also, there can only be one `Form2` opened at any moment.

This is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Form2 f2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (f2 != null) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Close form!");
            return;
        }

        f2 = new Form2();
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            this.IsMdiContainer = true;
            f2.MdiParent = this;
            f2.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            f2.Show();
        }

        f2.FormClosed += f2_FormClosed;

    }

    void f2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsMdiContainer = false;
        f2 = null;
    }

}
```

Everything works as it should except when I maximize `Form2` as MDI child and then close it. After that screen stays the same (as I even didn't closed `Form2`) but I am able to open new `Form2`, and then `Form1`'s title is "`Form1 - [Form2]`", and if I repeat the process it would be "`Form1 - [Form2] - [Form2]`", etc.

I figured out that I my `f2_FormClosed` method should be

```
    void f2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        f2.Hide(); // <<<<<<<<-----------NEW
        this.IsMdiContainer = false;
        f2 = null;
    }
```

but I don't know why; `Form2` should be closed, I don't know why should I have to hide it?!

Thanks!

Comment: Changing the IsMdiContainer property on a form whose window is created has *many* side-effects.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Hans, switching IsMdiContainer at run-time is wonky and is likely to produce other side-effects you haven't seen yet.

**Seriously consider a different design for your app.**

With that in mind, here's probably the stupidest hack I'll post all day:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Form2 f2;
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tmr.Interval = 100;
        tmr.Enabled = false;
        tmr.Tick += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e) {
            tmr.Stop();
            this.IsMdiContainer = false;
        };
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (f2 != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Close form!");
            return;
        }

        f2 = new Form2();
        f2.FormClosed += delegate(object sender2, FormClosedEventArgs e2) { 
            f2 = null; 
        };    
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            this.IsMdiContainer = true;
            f2.FormClosed += delegate(object sender3, FormClosedEventArgs e3) { 
                tmr.Start();
            };    
            f2.MdiParent = this;
        }
        f2.Show();
    }

}
```

*I originally tried Invoking the call to change IsMdiContainer but that didn't work, so I switched to the Timer.  Stupidity that works.  Use this solution with caution...